# Can we fix (stable) the public IP address of mobile?

Tags: networking, network-programming, ip-address, gsm, dhcp

Can we fix the public IP address of a mobile device?

In detail: Suppose I am traveling to different states of the country with a smart phone in which I have internet through a GSM SIM card. Its IP address is changing after some time interval.

I am referring to the public Home IP address - that we can find by surfing to *WhatismyIP* which gives, as an example, `145.233.66.202`. But after 2 days or after some hours if we check then it will have changed (like `149.222.33.12`) from previous one.

I want to make it stable; I want to use a static IP address.

Can I do it? Then how? Please share your idea with me.

Comment: Only your ISP can give you static public IP addresses. And for mobile phones, I do not think any ISP can provide it, especially when you move around.

Comment: My purpuse is not to use mobile phone but portable router instead of mobile (Suppose TP-LINK AC750 Dual Band 4G LTE Router w/4 Port – Archer MR200) which use GSM SIM card to access internet.
But I need this router IP address stable.
Because with this router I have some devices. And I am doing port forwarding task with this router. So I can access this devices remotly from any where. Just I need to know Public IP of Router.

But This IP chages after every time interval. Then How can I access it remotly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to know the IP address. The router you specified supports dyndns, a dynamic dns, so that you can connect to it without knowing the IP. When your IP changes, the dynamic DNS changes too.

Comment: Thanks Linkan for your kind support.
Can you tell me, If I use here any android phone(Suppose Samsung S7) instaed of mentioned TP link router.

And then I forwarding ports to my devices. and I access it remotly. In this case if ip address of mobile will be changed automatically, then also I can aceess  that device countinuosly remotly? 
Means dyndns works also in mobile or it depend on smart phone?

Comment: And one more question is,
Can I use Dyndns features free of cost? Or I have to make domian with some cost in no-ip or anyting else?

Comment: I have never looked at using dydns from phone, and I havn't lookedat prices in a couple of years.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remote control a Android phone I think that you should use a service like Teamviewer or similar.

So instead of connecting directly to a phone the phone and your computer connects to a server and the server passes the commands from one device to the other.

That way the IP address of the phone or computer does not matter. (Only the server's IP.)

Best Regards
/ Rasmus